# Test all checkbox combinations using Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular

In my Angular page there are 15 checkboxes and a label that when I select on each checkbox individually, a result will appear in the label. Plus when a checkbox click with a combination with others, the result will change in the label.

How can I run a Protractor loop to test these checkbox with a combination with each other, without involving with a lot of loops?

**More Explanation**

I have 15 checkboxes and I have to run a smoketest using Protractor. Run every possibility combination of these checkboxes and check the label that has the result to have expected result.
Now is there a simple way to run these checkboxes combinations!

Comment: It sounds like a question with many answers. Perhaps you can be more specific. Ideally if you also show your example code how you approached this problem.

Comment: Do you really want to verify all 225 combinations? When the label value is set by back-end logic, it might be better to create unit tests for the back-end code.

Comment: Does your application show 225 unique label text based on each combination?? I doubt that. If it doesn't display that many different label values , then we shouldn't  create that many test combinations.

Comment: Let's say it is creating 15 different label text covering all these 225 checkbox combinations then we can reduce it substantially to only make 15-20 checks only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a pagebject method `pageObject.selectCheckbox(idx)` which select a checkbox using index. and `pageObject.verify("Message")` which takes in the expected message and verifies its present.

```
let final = []
printCombination = function (arr, n, r) {
    data = Array(r)
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r)
}

combinationUtil = function (arr, data, start,
    end, index, r) {
    let i = ""
    if (index == r) {
        for (j of [...Array(r).keys()]) {
            i += data[j]
        }
        console.log(i)
        final.push(i)
        return i
    }

    i = start
    while (i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index) {
        data[index] = arr[i]
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
            end, index + 1, r)
        i += 1
    }
}

arr = [...Array(15).keys()]

n = arr.length

console.log(arr)
arr.forEach((val, r, array) => {
    printCombination(arr, n, r)
})

//print final to see the full combination list generated
final.forEach((a) => {

    [...a].forEach((idx) => {
        console.log("char", idx)
        pageObject.selectCheckbox(idx)
    })

    pageObject.verify("Message")


})
```

This will text all 15 combination ( Order ignored and no duplicates)

credit :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: Thank you that seems helpful. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: @PDhide, are you suggesting to test 225 checkbox combinations one by one and verifying label in UI? Do you think its correct & efficient approach?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal its an exhaustive approach if its that the user wants

Comment: Any automation purely reflects the quality of manual process its automating. Garbage in garbage out.